# CSS - Why can't I inline everything?

Tags: css

Here is the jsfiddle link please do take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/o9rf3thy/

There seems to be a problem with the html.

CSS

```
.taro{
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

I am still learning CSS so please do be patient with me.

I am trying to obtain this result
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lq80rkc4w5fqpki/Screenshot%202014-11-21%2017.36.51.png?dl=0

Comment: What do you want to 'inline'?

Comment: I want to inline everything that is inside the p tag? but only the first sentence is in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/89f5o3jL/2/

**CSS**

```
.list-group {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-group-item {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.img-circle {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.info {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}
.label {
    background: #5390fc;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <img src="http://placepic.me/profiles/60-60" width="60" height="60" class="img-circle">
        <div class="info">
            <strong>
                Crondeau Viner, MD
                <span>Nov 5th , 2014</span>
            </strong>
            <br />
            <span class="label">Note</span>
            <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh dear! Thank you so much! That's what I wanted.

Comment: Are you able to make the bottom line like this? 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/phmji7su2o13mrs/Screenshot%202014-11-21%2018.11.07.png?dl=0
@Bijomon Varghese

Comment: Thanks! However is it possible to make the line start after the profile picture? @Bijomon Varghese

Comment: BIG THANKS MAN :) 
How I hope I can give rep.

Comment: @failedStudent Gald that it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Items that have `display:inline` either by default or by setting are **not affected by margins**.

What I think you require is `display:inline-block`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o9rf3thy/1/)

This might be useful [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer! 

However my image actually went down. Take a look at this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ph7oskfvdy8ibzg/Screenshot%202014-11-21%2017.55.11.png?dl=0

Comment: See the answer by Mauro and my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your html contains several invalid tags:

- you should use a self closing tag for `img` i.e. end it with `/>` instead of `>`
- you should use `<br />` instead of `<br>`

I would also consider changing the nesting of your tags so the `spans` don't contain `br` tags as it makes it easier to follow and style correctly.

Finally, if you want to make all the text display to the right of the image change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnuptjm4/))

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <img src="http://placepic.me/profiles/80-80" width="40" height="40" class="img-circle" />
    <p class="taro">
      <strong>
        <b>Crondeau Viner, MD</b>
        <label>
          Nov 5th , 2014
        </label>
      </strong>
      <br />Note
      <br /> 
      <span>hello Dr Jacqueline test - nov 5  </span>    
      <br />
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And your CSS would become

```
.taro{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that break tags should not be used for spacing, that's what margins / padding are for and wrapping is best served by a `div` and not a `p` tag. Also `b` tags have been re-purposed under HTML5.

Comment: @Paulie_D However, if that's the case means I have to create a class for every sentence? To trigger the margins. 

Thanks for the answer! However, my results is different. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ph7oskfvdy8ibzg/Screenshot%202014-11-21%2017.55.11.png?dl=0

Comment: No separate classes are not specifically required. Use of the correct elements (which have their own default properties and layouts)  would solve a lot of your issues.

Comment: I think I got what you meant. Means I remove all the `br` and change them into div classes?